# Adding connection settings during runtime for Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, appsettings, azure-functions-runtime

I'm searching for ways to modify and edit app settings for Azure function during runtime.

from the links below, I was able to find how to add bindings locally and add connection settings through azure portal or Azure Cli

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#environment-variables

However, I'm searching for ways to generate new connection setting variables as well as new bindings at runtime.

The use case would be, where we need to onboard users without manually interacting with the Azure function app configuration.

I also tried modifying it thorough an example given in below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#environment-variables

I was able to modify the variable temporarily, but it appears that it loses the changes as soon as the run gets terminated (also, it didn't work when I published the app on Azure).

Is there way to accomplish this during runtime?

My set up is to have two azure functions:
1. dedicated to modifying app settings if change is detected in CosmosDB where new user information is added.
2. dedicated sending messages, but generating bindings based on app configurations added by azure function 1.

My initial thoughts were to store the whole app settings in cosmosDB and generate appsettings based on that document at every onetime, but I'm pretty sure there is better ways to do this.

also, it looks like my connection strings in local.settings.json don't get reflected when I actually publish them. what am I missing?

Thanks, in advance :)

Comment: local.setting.json question answered https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1594

Comment: How do you modify your app settings, based on your new user info or just add new connection strings? And send message to where? A storage connected by your app settings or a cosmos db?